# libKal.a depends on itself

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to get [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) working in Xcode 4.3.2 and after following most of what I've found on stackoverflow, I'm getting the following error:

```
File /Users/arigold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MLTM-dypybtiwtxqyjmbbqsvdtrbnjckz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libKal.a depends on itself.  This target might include its own product.
```

I'm sure that once I get a grasp on how the whole linking static libraries thing works, this will be easy..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I removed libKal.a from the "Link Binaries with Libraries" in the Build Phases section of Kal.xcodeproj.  Steps:

1. Click on Kal.xcodeproj in the Project Navigator (left-most column)
2. Click on "Kal" under Targest (one column over to the right)
3. Click on the Build Phases tab (wide center column)
4. Under the section "Link Binaries with Libraries" delete libKal.a

Makes sense - it can't very well link to (depend on) itself, now can it.